# Example of both finitely and infinitely generated free modules which are direct sum of two non free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Does there exist non free $R$-modules $F_0,F_1$ such that $F=F_0\oplus F_1$ be a free $R$-module?

1- If yes then for what kind of rings $R$ there exist such $R$ modules?

2- If yes then does it holds for both finitely and infinitely generated free $R$-module $F$?

Comment: You might want to learn about projective modules, which provide many example. For a fun elementary example, Let $R = \mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, and let $I = (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. Then $I$ is not a principal ideal and so is not free. But $R \oplus R \simeq I \oplus I$ as $R$-modules via the map 

$$(x,y) \mapsto (2 x + y (1 + \sqrt{-5}),(1 - \sqrt{-5}) x + 2 y).$$

For ideals $I$ and $J$, $I \oplus J \simeq R \oplus IJ$, so this explicit construction implicitly uses that $I^2 =(2)$ is principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring $F_2\times F_2$.

$I=F_2\times \{0\}$ is not free, because it has a nonzero annihilator $J=\{0\}\times F_2$. The same can be said for $J$, having $I$ as its annihlator. But $I\oplus J\cong R$ is free.

To produce an infinitely generated free module example, just consider $I'=\oplus_{i=1}^\infty I$ which also has annihilator $J$, as a summand of $\oplus_{i=1}^\infty R$ with complement $J'=\oplus_{i=1}^\infty J$.